# How to Aggregate QuerySet for Arbitrary Keys Group By

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-orm

```
<QuerySet [
    {'id': 520, 'Commission': None, 'Effective Date': '2019-12-11 00:00:00+00'},
    {'id': 520, 'Commission': 30, 'Effective Date': None}
]>
```

Suppose I had a Django QuerySet like the above, with an arbitrary number of matching keys where only one is expected to not be null per key.

How do I get a result like the following per `id` as if I'm grouping by `id`?

```
<QuerySet [
    {'id': 520, 'Commission': 30, 'Effective Date': '2019-12-11 00:00:00+00'}
]>
```

Comment: Add a filter. Model.objects.filter(commission__isnull=False)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use annotate method, refer the aggregation topic: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/aggregation/

```
Your_model.objects.values('id', 'date').annotate(total_commission=Sum('commission')).order_by('id'))
```